# Conjugacy in SO(1,2)

Tags: group-theory

I have one question:
Is there an element $g \in SO(1,2)$ such that
$$
g^{-1}\begin{pmatrix}
\cosh\psi & \sinh\psi & 0\\
-\sinh\psi & -\cosh\psi & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -1
\end{pmatrix}g = \begin{pmatrix}
\cosh\psi & \sinh\psi & 0\\
\sinh\psi & \cosh\psi & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}?
$$

If $\psi \not= 0$, of course not. Just look at the spectrum.

Comment: What do $ch$ and $sh$ mean?

Comment: It is hyperbolic sine and cosine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no $g \in SO(1, 2)$ (or even $g \in GL(3)$) satisfying the desired property.

Recall that $\operatorname{trace}(AB) = \operatorname{trace}(BA)$ so $\operatorname{trace}(g^{-1}Ag) = \operatorname{trace}(g^{-1}gA) = \operatorname{trace}(A)$. The trace of the left hand side is $-1$ while the trace of the right hand side is $2\cosh\psi + 1 \geq 2 + 1 = 3$; in particular, they are not equal.